# Unable to use PDO inside class

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I've a simple class, User which requires database access. I also require database access in several other classes, so my class.user.php looks like this:

```
include "config.php"

class User {

    public $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db){
        $this->db = $db;
        global $db;
    }

    function LastLogin(){
        // global $db; // if I uncomment this, it works for this function. 
        $pdo = $db->prepare("SELECT last_login FROM users WHERE username = ?");
        $pdo->execute(array($username));
        while($r = $pdo->fetchObject()){
            echo $r->last_login;
        }
    }
}
```

Config.php looks like this:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$db = new PDO($dsn,'user','pass', $opt);
```

So let's say I have page called userdetails.php, and I want to know when the user has last logged in.

```
$user = new User($db);
$user->LastLogin();
```

This results in a error message like this:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in /home/www/class.user.php on line 12 
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in/home/www/class.user.php on line 12
```

So I'm having problems with using pdo inside the class. It makes no sense to type "global $db" to every function, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Did that, no noticeable changes.

Comment: You really need to stop using global.  It blows apart encapsulation, one of the reasons for using OOP.

Comment: @KevinM1 Yeah, I tried not to use it, but it was the only way I could make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
include "config.php"

class User {

    public $db;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->db = $db;
      }

    function LastLogin(){
        $pdo = $this->db->prepare("SELECT last_login FROM users WHERE username = ?");
        $pdo->execute(array($username));
        while($r = $pdo->fetchObject()){
            echo $r->last_login;
        }
    }
}
```

The `global $db` is definitely not required and is bad practice as it destroys the encapsulation of a class.

The type hint PDO in `__construct(PDO $db)` is also not actually legal as far as I know.

And while you have a property of `$db` and loaded it with the correct handle, to use it chnage this

```
$pdo = $db->prepare("SELECT last_login FROM users WHERE username = ?");
```

To

```
$pdo = $this->db->prepare("SELECT last_login FROM users WHERE username = ?");
```

So you are using/addressing it correctly.

Comment: That solved it. Is there a way to use $db instead of $this->db?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: One reason only: easier to remember and faster to type. Maybe that's two reasons. But if it's not possible I can live with that.

Comment: Thats the language construct. Using it is self documentary, you will find that useful later when you come back to add something new or fix a bug

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, remove the line:

```
global $db;
```

Also, you don't need to pass the `PDO` either.

And instead of trying to reference it as

```
$db->prepare(....)
```

You want to reference it as:

```
$this->db->prepare(....)
```

since you're instantiating it as a variable accessible within the class.

Answer (score 1):

`global $db` is the problem. Loose it and it all should work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `global $db` from your constructor.

Use `$this->db` instead of `$db` in `function LastLogin`